# VBA: How to close Excel.Application after a crash

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

My Word macro uses this code to open and access an Excel workbook:

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\Filename.xls")   

 ' Main procedure

exWb.Close
Set exWb = Nothing

objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Since I'm still debugging, the macro often stops before reaching the Close and Quit commands, leaving an instance of Excel and the workbook open in the background.

I can sometimes close them by opening Task Manager and ending the tasks, but I doubt that's the best solution. Is there a macro I can write in Word that closes all open Workbooks and quits all (background) instances of Excel?

Comment: Does it stop because you are stopping it or because there is an error?  if the latter then use On Error resume next (or goto <label>) to ensure you are closing the workbooks.

Comment: You can use GetObject() to attach to open instances of Excel and clean them up.  It might be tricky if there are more than one instance though - there's no way to tell GetObject which one to return...

Comment: Sorceri: That preventive approach occured to me literally minutes before I saw your answer, but I'm upvoting you anyway!

Comment: Tim: I'm not familiar with GetObject. Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: @TimWilliams according to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288902) if you know the name, you can get the correct one.

Comment: @findwindow - yes, if you have a distinctively-named file which you know is open that approach would work.

Comment: @TimWilliams so besides setting the book, I can set another variable to hold same book via `getobject` then when book crashes, i can retrieve it via the other variable? Edit: no, variable only needs to hold the name, not object. That's what `getobject` is for XD Edit2: wait, you said `is open`...

Comment: If your VB code exits due to an unhandled exception then any variables will get cleared, so you can't store the workbook name in that situation.  Your best bet is to do as ASH outlined and use error handling to make sure you can recover in the event of a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is the traditional way to deal with such anomalies:

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application, exWb As Excel.Workbook
    On Error GoTo Cleanup

    Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\Filename.xls")

    ' Main procedure

Cleanup:
    If Err.number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error " & Err.number & ": " & Err.Description
    If Not exWb Is Nothing Then exWb.Close False
    If Not objExcel Is Nothing Then objExcel.Quit
End Sub
```